# Pandas add values in one column for all the same values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have found a couple examples of the same problems in previous post but none addresses Python and pandas situation. i am new to python and i am struggling. I have made huge progress before updating this post, i am super close.

i am trying to sum up the values in 'Quantity' for all the dates that identical in the 'date' column. Currently, they are there but they do not add together, additionally, I am trying to get the last column values to make a list.

here is my code and what the table look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Date': ['01-01-2018', '01-01-2018','02-01-2018','03-01-2018','03-01-2018'], 'Quantity' : ['4','5','6','2','8'], 'Id':['5674','565','67433','2353','579']})


data = df.groupby(['Date','Quantity'])
result = data['Id'].unique()

print(result)
```

and the outcome is:

```
Date        Quantity
01-01-2018  4            [5674]
            5             [565]
02-01-2018  6           [67433]
03-01-2018  2            [2353]
            8             [579]
```

the outcome is not matching what I would like and I am not sure why! I appreciate has any hint about how to proceed. thank you!

Comment: Did you forget to include something in your post? You say `here is my code and what the table look like` but I don't see the table. Could you include some test data so that people can run the code for themselves?

Comment: A tip: When working with pandas you rarely need numpy, and when working with either of the two explicit loops should be a last resort. Pandas and numpy are powerful tools which can handle most use cases.

Comment: yes sorry the table was so bad it would not be proper to paste it here. thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Group by `Data` and apply below aggregation functions

- column `Quantity` : Sum
- column `Id` : list

```
df.groupby(['Date']).agg({'Quantity': sum, 'Id': list}).reset_index()
```

Output

```
    Date        Quantity    Id
0   01-01-2018  45          [5674, 565]
1   02-01-2018  6           [67433]
2   03-01-2018  28          [2353, 579]
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way of having the duplicated dates removed? This is my original idea to have no duplicates in dates, the total quantity for each and the list the ids contributing to the quantity. Do I make sense?

Comment: @LeLionJaune check the updated answer. Its becomes easy to answer if you can frame the question clearly :)

Comment: Mujjiga, I had never seen this function (agg) before. Thank you so much, is there a requirement to reset the index there?

Comment: jezrael, Mujjiga, sorry for miss-explaining my problem.

Comment: @LeLionJaune without `reset_index` it returns a dataframe with multilevel index. `reset_index` resets it to one level.